# Access и поле со списком\флажки

Tags: ms-access

Подскажите, как сделать и можно ли:

Нужно, чтобы при выборе значений в поле со списком или (если реализовывать всё флажками) при выборе нескольких флажков имена этих полей\флажков (или можно иначе как-то?) записывались в определённую таблицу и в определённое поле.

Например. Есть форма. В форме флажки: Молоко, Хлеб, Сахар, Соль. Отмечаю Молоко - в таблицу Продукты в поле Заказ записывается 1 (Или слово Молоко. Выбираю Соль - записывается цифра 18 (или слово соль). Примерно так.

Почему флажки? Потому что значений на выбора больше 40 у меня быть не может. Это не много.

Подскажите, как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поле со списком (комбобокс), то в controlsource укажите имя поля, в котором должно храниться значение. Чтобы в качестве значения записывалось число,  можно прописать в rowsource комбобокса таблицу или запрос с двумя полями, первое из которых число (значение), а во втором хранится текст - тогда при указании columnwidths 0 число выводиться не будет. Аналогично можно поступить с флажками, разместив их в группе переключателей и задав в controlsource группы поле для хранения значения (сами числа прописываются в optionvalue флажков).

Comment: А можете пример кода показать? Или ссылка на примеры? Просто в vba я вообще нуб.

Comment: Не могу - у меня макось.

Comment: так хоть бы тут напечатать приблизительно, чтобы ещё у кого более определённо спросить...(

Comment: Так я все напечатал. Акцесс все равно не позволяет полноценно создавать формы на лету, а для визуального конструктора моей инструкции должно быть достаточно.

Comment: спасибо) Надеюсь хоть сейчас мне помогут, а то уже недели 2 точно бьюсь - нет результата.

Comment: Вам нужна еще какая-то помощь? Спрашивайте.

Comment: Да нужна. Как я уже говорил, я в VBA вообще не разбираюсь...

Comment: Это не место, где сделают работу за вас. Если есть вопросы - обращайтесь.